# UITableView grouped background image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am setting `UITableView` grouped image but it showing all over the table i want that it should like 
below in second table it should background image only the area of cells and  tables not that grey border which are in second table thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Following code.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

For Another way to set backgroung image for grouped `UITableView` read [This documentation.](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-add-a-nice-background-image-to-your-grouped-table-view/40/)

Comment: but it add side image also for grouped table

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewBackground.png"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame]; 
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
[tempImageView release];
```

Answer (score -2):

> Instead of giving the background image to table.Provide the background image/color to cell.

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

since colorWithPattern is very expensive which causes memory leak,avoid using colorWithPatternImage

instead you can use 
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor initWithRed:0.25 green:0.25 blue:0.25 alpha:1];


//change the RGB as per the image
```

Comment: here we want to display the background of cell not the tableview.

Comment: hello i read that bhai. if you know only one way of finding the solution means pls be quite.here are thousands of other ways to play around.

Comment: yes so please apply the solution which i provided.instead voting and passing the time.SF...